# Объединение двух селектов

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть 2 селекта, которые выбирают все таблицы и все столбцы этих таблиц для выбранной схемы. Для столбцов выодится тип и имя столбца. Для таблиц - просто `TABLE`.

```
SELECT table_name,
       column_name,
       CASE data_type
        WHEN 'NUMBER' THEN 'NUM'
        WHEN 'VARCHAR2' THEN 'VAR2'
        WHEN 'DATE' THEN 'DATE'
       END as type
FROM user_tab_columns
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT table_name,
       'TABLE',
       'TABLE'
FROM user_tab_columns;
```

Возможно ли как-то сделать то же самое через один `SELECT` без `UNION`?

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| table_name | column_name |  type |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| ORDER      | ID          | NUM   |
| ORDER      | PRICE       | NUM   |
| ORDER      | DATE        | DATE  |
| ORDER      | TABLE       | TABLE |
|    ....    |     ....    |  ...  |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строки для таблицы можно рассматривать как строки итогов, подводимые под данными о каждой таблице, только суммировать нам нечего, но это не беда. Оператор [ROLLUP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm#i1007413) создает строки итогов в нужном нам разрезе, при этом что либо суммировать совершенно не обязательно:

```
SELECT table_name,
       nvl(column_name,'TABLE'),
       decode(data_type,NULL,'TABLE','NUMBER','NUM','VARCHAR2','VAR2',data_type) as type
  FROM user_tab_columns
 GROUP BY ROLLUP(table_name,(column_name,data_type))
HAVING table_name is not null
```

Так как нам нужен итог по каждой таблице, то первым параметром ROLLUP мы даем имя таблицы. Итоги по колонкам и типам данных нам не нужны, поэтому эти два поля идут в отдельных скобках, вторым параметром. Но rollup пытается подвести еще общий итог по всей выборке, его отличает то, что колонка table_name будет для него NULL, в условии having мы отсеиваем эту строку.

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что Вы можете использовать hierarchical query

```
select distinct table_name,
                decode(lvl, 1, column_name, 'TABLE') column_name,
                decode(lvl, 1, decode(data_type, 'NUMBER', 'NUM', 'VARCHAR2', 'VAR2', data_type), 'TABLE') type
  from user_tab_columns s
 cross join (select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 2)
 where s.table_name = 'EMPLOYEES';
```

Comment: Спасибо, довольно интересный способ через рекурсивные запросы.

Comment: @compl Этот способ и без рекурсивных бы работал, ему надо размножить строки. рекурсия по факту делает `select 1 lvl from dual union all select 2 from dual`. И лично я бы вместо cross добавил бы условие соединения `s.column_id=1 or lvl=1` тогда бы размножилась только первая колонка каждой таблицы и distinct был бы не нужен, что возможно даже дало бы некоторый выигрыш у ROLLUP по скорости