# Сложный запрос Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. У меня проблема с объединением трёх запросов. Вот мои 3 запроса:

```
select brigade_number from task_execution
join brigade on task_execution.brigade_id = brigade.brigade_id
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
select count(status) from task_execution
where status = 'Выполнено'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
select task, status, data, time, work_comment from task_execution
join brigade on task_execution.brigade_id = brigade.brigade_id
join tasks on task_execution.tasks_id = tasks.tasks_id
where status = 'Выполнено'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как мне нужно что бы это выглядело. Нужно что бы сначала шли 2 клетки, номер бригады, и количество выполненных задач для этой бригады, то есть в моём случае "7" "2", номер бригады и количество выполненных задач у этой бригады соответственно, а потом уже ниже мой третий запрос с выборкой полных данных по каждой выполненной задаче. Дальше следующая бригада в моём случае "9" "1" и количество выполненных задач соответственно и так же строки с выборкой данных. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это так реализовать и как нужно объединить 3 моих запроса в 1 такой который я описал. Спасибо заранее.
У меня получилось объеденить номер бригады и количество выполненных задач на бригаду:

```
select brigade_number, count(status) from task_execution
join brigade on task_execution.brigade_id = brigade.brigade_id
where status = 'Выполнено'
group by brigade_number having count(*)>0
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть как заголовок идёт строчка с номером бригады и количеством выполненных задач и под ней уже список этих самых задач с развёрнутыми данными. Грубо говоря мне нужно между этими двумя строчками на последнем скриншоте вколотить результат третьего скриншота. Ну само собой что между ними пойдут результаты которые относятся конкретно к 7 бригаде а в самом низу уже к 9 бригаде соответственно. Надеюсь я объяснил доходчиво. Если всё же не поняли. Напишите попробую ещё как нибудь объяснить попонятнее. Спасибо за ответ заранее.
Вот скрин того как это должно выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запрос возвращает данные в табличном виде. Покажите желаемый результат в виде таблицы, а не текстом. А то сейчас выходит, что у вас идет запись с одним набором колонок, а за ней тут же запись с другим набором и даже другим количеством колонок

Comment: @Mike я подкорректировал тему поглядите последнее изменение. Надеюсь получилось объяснить понятно.

Comment: А почему вы не хотите, в excel например, нарисовать как совместно это должно  выглядеть в виде одной таблицы. А то ведь у вас все равно получается, что после строки с 2 колонками, (7,2) должны быть строки с 5 колонками. А так не бывает, в результате или 2 колонки или 5, хотя часть колонок конечно может быть пустой. И что то мне подсказывает, что эти количества выглядят как итоги и значит нам нужен group by с `ROLLUP` и возможно сортировкой с функцией `grouping()` что бы "итоги" , были перед самими данным

Comment: @Mike Да вы правильно поняли, сначала идёт строчка с двумя колонками потом с пятью, потом о5 с двумя потом о5 с пятью и сколько раз это будет повторятся зависит от того сколько всего есть бригад и есть ли у них выполненные задачи. Но если будет проще я сейчас сделаю в экселе это и выставлю сюда скрин

Comment: @Mike я ещё раз подправил изначальный вопрос, там есть скрин того как это должно быть. Спасибо за ответ заранее.

Comment: И еще раз  повторяю "_так не бывает_". Если нужен именно такой вид, то это должна сделать программа выводящая на  экран. SQL возвращает всегда одинаковый набор колонок у всех записей. Самым простым был бы такой вид http://clip2net.com/s/3JnIpLr, немного поизвращавшись можно подавить значения в колонках номер бригады и количество в строках с данными, но на клиенте при выводе на экран это будет сделать гораздо проще, чем на SQL

Comment: И если тот вид, что я привел устраивает, вам нужно что то вроде этого http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647266/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2/647298#647298 только всякие там decode не нужны, просто взять max() от всех колонок и добавить колонку `count(*)`

Comment: @Mike Да я думаю оптимальным будет тогда уж сделать 2 грида, в один из них добавить запрос что я накалякал который пишет номер бригады и количество выполненных заданий а во второй грид уже выборку с подробными данными об этих заданиях. Спасибо что объяснили.

Answer (score 1):

Такой запрос можно составить используя конструкцию GROUP BY ROLLUP().

```
select 
    case when grouping(task) = 0 then null else brigade_number end brigade_number, 
    case when grouping(task) = 0 then null else count(status) end cnt,
    task, status, data, time, work_comment 
from task_execution
    join brigade on task_execution.brigade_id = brigade.brigade_id
    join tasks on task_execution.tasks_id = tasks.tasks_id
where status = 'Выполнено'
group by rollup(brigade_number, (task, status, data, time, work_comment))
```

Приведённый запрос выводит итоговые(групповые) строки после данных группы.
Чтобы поднять их наверх каждой группы можно результат запроса вывести в обратном порядке с помощью ROWNUM:

```
select r.* 
from (
    /* select */
) r
order by rownum desc
```